# I don't know how to write rules on Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an Auth and Firestore project on Firebase. I'm quite new at Firebase. I don't know how to write rules.
I want to write a rule that a user can read and write only one's documents. Can you help me how I can write such rule? You can see the collection below.
[A screenshot of my collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D85ZT.png)

And also the user:
[User info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCoul.png)

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow only authenticated content owners access
    match /some_collection/{userId}/{documents=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId
    }
  }
}
```

I tried applying this rule but I couldn't achive.

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) will help.

Answer (score 0):

The first time the user creates the document, add a field 'author' with the uid of the user. In order to allow the user to create the document add this rule:

```
allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
```

Then add this rule to only allow the user to access its document (with the 'resource.data.someField' you can access the document fields):

```
allow read, update, delete: if resource.data.author == request.auth.uid
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try asap. Have great day :)

Comment: You don't to add the UID of the user in a field of the document if the ID of the document is itself the user's UID.

Comment: It's true Doug, for users I would do like:

allow update: if resource.id == request.auth.uid ;

Comment: With resource.id you get the ID of the document (in this case the ID of the document is the UID of the user)